# How to map to a mapping key?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I remapped `q` to `LShift`, and now I can't map any other key to `q` except `RShift + q` (via another mapping), which gives `Q` - so each time I must copy/paste `q` from elsewhere. When I try mapping to `q`, it makes the standard windows error sound, and nothing is typed.

Is it possible to map to a mapping key?

---

**Scripts used**:

```
q::LShift   # the "mapping key", q
>+q::q      # to allow Q via RShift; deleting this doesn't help the below
k::q        # doesn't work
LAlt & q::q # doesn't work
^Numpad8::q # doesn't work
```

---

**Additional info**:

- **System**: Win-10 Home, ASUS ROG Strix [GL702VSK](https://amzn.to/2TAedUh)
- **AHK version**: 1.1.29.01
- **Drivers**: *HID Keyboard Device* (x2), *PC/AT Enhanced PS/2 Keyboard (101/102-Key)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try mapping to `q`, it makes the standard Windows error sound and nothing is typed.

With [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) 1.1.30.03 <sup>1</sup>:

```
q::LShift           ; Send LShift via q
>+q::q              ; Allow "Q" via RShift
k::q                ; Should work as-is i.e. type "q"
LAlt & q::Send q    ; As above. Use Send "q", rather than just "q".
^Numpad8::Send q    ; As above. Use Send "q", rather than just "q".
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *The latest version of AutoHotkey is 1.1.32.00 as of February 2020.*

---